# What were the pills that Mark was taking?

Tags: welcome-to-marwen

In *Welcome to Marwen*, Mark is taking blue pills. We learn from his caregiver that he is only to take one each day, but they are addictive. Indeed, we see him taking more than one and telling his caretaker that he is dropping them down the sink in order to get more of them.

What are these pills? Are they anti-psychotics intended to help him deal with mental illness? Are they painkillers? Are they something else?

Comment: I am also interested if the name Deja Thoris is in any way connected to some pill/drug name?